# Evil: How to add key binding for changing buffers?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

With Evil mode, `:bn` shows the next buffer, and `:bp` shows the previous buffer. I wish to define a custom key binding where `<Space>n` shows the next buffer, and `<Space>p` shows the previous buffer.

In Vim, this can be accomplished using:

```
nnoremap <leader>n :bnext<cr>
nnoremap <leader>p :bprevious<cr>
```

where `<leader>` is <kbd>Space</kbd>.

How can I define these key bindings for Evil mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something like this in my config,
inspired by [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs):

```
(use-package evil
  :init
  (use-package evil-leader
    :commands (evil-leader-mode global-evil-leader-mode)
    :demand
    :config
    (evil-leader/set-leader "SPC")
    (global-evil-leader-mode t))
  :config
  (evil-mode 1))

(evil-leader/set-key
  "bn" 'next-buffer
  "bp" 'previous-buffer)
```

this requires to type `SPC b n` or `SPC b p`,
which I recommend becasue it makes more room for other bindings,

but you can remove the `b`s in the last two lines there, if you prefer the shorter binding.